# I don't get any output when I scrape amazon using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape data about helmets from Amazon.
This is the [link](https://www.amazon.in/s?k=helmets+for+men&i=automotive&rh=n%3A4772060031%2Cp_89%3ASteelbird%7CStudds%7CVega%2Cp_36%3A150000-200000&dc&page=2&qid=1629448200&rnid=5814682031&ref=sr_pg_2)

I tried to remove the classes using dot separators and I also tried using select(). But I always get an empty list. Please help me to scrape the data

I'm using Brave Browser which is similar to Chrome.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

for n in range(1,15):
    url = f"https://www.amazon.in/s?k=helmets+for+men&i=automotive&rh=n%3A4772060031%2Cp_89%3ASteelbird%7CStudds%7CVega%2Cp_36%3A150000-200000&dc&page={n}&qid=1629448200&rnid=5814682031&ref=sr_pg_{n}"

    page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

    for title in soup.find_all('span', attrs = {'class' : ['a-size-base-plus', 'a-color-base', 'a-text-normal']}):
        print(title)
```

Comment: I have run your code on my side and I have get output as below :

`<span class="a-size-base a-color-base" dir="auto">Bikers destination</span>`


`<span class="a-size-base a-color-base" dir="auto">RAJ AUTO AGENCIES</span>`

`...`

`<span class="a-size-base a-color-base" dir="auto">Include Out of Stock</span>`

Answer (score 2):

To get correct response from the server, add `User-Agent` HTTP header to the request:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:91.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/91.0"
}

for n in range(1, 15):
    url = f"https://www.amazon.in/s?k=helmets+for+men&i=automotive&rh=n%3A4772060031%2Cp_89%3ASteelbird%7CStudds%7CVega%2Cp_36%3A150000-200000&dc&page={n}&qid=1629448200&rnid=5814682031&ref=sr_pg_{n}"

    page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")

    for title in soup.select("h2:has(a)"):
        print(title.get_text(strip=True))
```

Prints:

```
Steelbird SBH-17 Terminator ABS Material Shell Full Face Graphic Helmet Fitted with Clear Visor and Extra Smoke Visor (Medium 580 mm, Matt Black Grey)
Steelbird Off Road Turf Motocross Helmet with Extra Clear Visor (Large 600 MM, Glossy Fluo Red Helmet Fitted with Clear Visor and Extra Smoke Visor)
Steelbird SB-45 OSKA Flip Up Helmet with Reflective Graphics (X-Large 620 MM, Matt Black with Clear Visor)
Vega - Shell OR-D/V-DK_M Off Road D/V Black Helmet - M, Expanded Polystyrene and ABS
Vega - OR-D/V-SKT-DKS_M Off Road D/V Sketch Helmet (Dull Black Silver , Medium), ABS and Expanded Polystyrene

...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Andrej Kesely. I'm new to scraping so may I know what does that "h2:has(a)" do? This is in the 14th line.

Comment: @CephasPrincely `h2:has(a)` is a CSS selector. it means select all `<h2>` tags which contain an `<a>` tag.

Comment: On the same [website]https://www.amazon.in/s?k=helmets+for+men&i=automotive&rh=n%3A4772060031%2Cp_89%3ASteelbird%7CStudds%7CVega%2Cp_36%3A150000-200000&dc&page=2&qid=1629448200&rnid=5814682031&ref=sr_pg_2, can I use this CSS selector ["a:has(span)"] to get the name of the item?